# Como tratar filtros complexos em requisições Rest API?

Tags: rest, restful

Em Rest APIs as boas práticas recomendam:

- `GET` - Listar dados;
- `POST` - Ìnserir dados;
- `PUT` - Atualizar dados;
- `DELETE` - Apagar dados.

Seguindo as boas práticas, para recuperar uma lista de dados devemos utilizar `GET` e para os filtros devemos utilizar *query string*.

#### Dúvida

No caso de filtros complexos, de 25 campos ou mais e/ou um filtro que contém um array de `ids`, que pode gerar uma URL com mais de 2048 caracteres (sendo uma má prática).

Qual seria a "melhor" abordagem a ser utilizada?

- Enviar o filtro no *Header* no padrão JSON?
- Utilizar o método `POST` em vez do método `GET`?
- Outra solução?